# How to check if the function returns a list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code. I want to scrape emails from a url. Sometimes its gives 500 error if the url given is an image url. I want to get rid of that error to determing if function returns on list of strings.

```
       Try
        Dim inStream As StreamReader
        Dim webRequest As WebRequest
        Dim webresponse As WebResponse
        Dim contents As String
        webRequest = webRequest.Create(url)
        webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
        inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
        contents = inStream.ReadToEnd()

        Dim adrRx As Regex = New Regex("\b[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b")
        Dim emails As New List(Of String)
        For Each item As Match In adrRx.Matches(contents.ToLower)
            emails.Add(item.ToString)
        Next
        Return emails
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `Nothing` if it fails.

And then of course test if the outcome is not nothing:

```
If ScrapeMail(MyUrl) IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Succes!")
Else
        MsgBox("No succes...")
End If
```